# HTML5 Draw Canvas - Count number of clicks

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a HTML5 draw canvas over an image that allows users to draw dots on top of the image:

JAVASCRIPT

```
var sketcher = null;
var brush = null;

$(document).ready(function(e) {

  brush = new Image();
  brush.src = 'assets/brush2.png';
  brush.onload = function(){
    sketcher = new Sketcher( "sketch", brush );
  }

 });
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="sketch" width="1024" height="687" />
<canvas id="draw"/>

<div class="id1462-Main-Window"><img src="images/1462_Main_Window.jpg"
 width="1024"height="687" alt=""/>
```

I am trying to add the function that when the user clicks/draws a dot in the canvas area, a counter steps by +1.

```
<p id="counter_text"><span>0</span></p>
```

Comment: Increment the counter on onClick event

Comment: I couldn't resist to ask: Shouln't your gamearea height be `768` instead?

Comment: Has to be 687 due to a banner at the bottom taking up the rest of the space.

Comment: Do you have a JSfiddle so i can see the code and figure how it works?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
      canvas.addEventListener('click', function() { 
          $("#counter_text").val($("#counter_text").val() += 1);
      }, false);
});
```

Comment: I added this into the javascript portion of my code however the counter is still not outputting the increments.

Comment: I also have some css code in the html:                                #counter_text {
    z-index:10;
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:385px;
    top:-25px;
  } This might be conflicting with the example you gave.

Comment: did you put it in the onload event?

$(function(){
      canvas.addEventListener('click', function() { 
          $("#counter_text").val($("#counter_text").val() += 1);
      }, false);
});